# Displaying an item from css through php

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm actually making a skin menu, like an input/output => show on skin option on my wordpress skin to make it easier for a user to use it. However, I've been trying to get the logo to show up, but keeps failing... I've merged CSS with PHP to make it able to take the function name; but it does not show the image in the background.

Here's the css/php file, called bg_image.php.

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>

#logo_main{
    background:url('<?php echo get_settings('ld_header_img'); ?>') no-repeat;
}
```

By including it to the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bg_image.php" />
```

And of course, the functions.php, which has the arrays and such for the thing to work...

```
$themename = "LightD";
$shortname = "ld";

$options = array (

array( "name" => $themename." Options",
    "type" => "title"),

array( "name" => "Homepage",
    "type" => "section"),
array( "type" => "open"),

array( "name" => "Homepage header image",
    "desc" => "Enter the link to an image used for the homepage header.",
    "id" => $shortname."_header_img",
    "type" => "text",
    "std" => ""),

array( "type" => "close"),
array( "name" => "Footer",
    "type" => "section"),
array( "type" => "open"),

array( "name" => "Footer copyright text",
    "desc" => "Enter text used in the right side of the footer. It can be HTML",
    "id" => $shortname."_footer_text",
    "type" => "text",
    "std" => ""),

array( "type" => "close")

);
```

**NOTICE** That the full functions.php source/sample can be found in the following link below; I looked upon this topic to get this info working:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-create-a-better-wordpress-options-panel/

Where:

> name: The name of the input field.
>
> desc: A short description explaining what it is to the user.
>
> id: the id of the field, prefixed by the shortname. It will be used to store as well as access the options.
>
> type: the input type – select, text or textarea
>
> options: used to declare an array of options for a select type input.
>
> std: the default input value, used if no other input is given.

Here's where my question comes to place... I've tried using "style" inside the , and it worked:

```
<div id="logo_main" style="background:url('<?php echo get_settings('ld_header_img'); ?>') no-repeat;">
<div id="branding">
<div id="blog-title"><?php if ( is_singular() ) {} else {echo '<h1>';} ?><a href="<?php echo /*home_url()*/"./home/" ?>/" title="<?php bloginfo( 'name' ) ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ) ?></a><?php if ( is_singular() ) {} else {echo '</h1>';} ?></div>
<p id="blog-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ) ?></p>
</div>
</div>
```

My question is; why doesn't the CSSed PHP doesn't work?!

Comment: Where is `get_settings()` defined? Are you ever actually including whatever file defines it in your css/php file?

Comment: get_settings() is in the functions.php; If you've seen the link I've posted, it clearly explains how the functions.php works.

Comment: You should localize the component causing the problem in the first place. That is, it is meaningless to ask "why doesn't my div have a background" (and even more meaningless to ask that without showing the entire actual code). The right question would be more like e.g. "The following PHP script (...source code follows...) produces the following result (...result code follows...)" or "The following resulting css (...resulting css code follows...) doesn't make my div on this page (...resulting html code follows...) to have the background".

Comment: Alright, I'll provide as much possible code as I can, because the functions.php is over 200 lines (I don't think it'll look ok to have bunch of code on a page? Or would it?) Although, the rest of the code, (the html and css are complete.) I provided a link where it shows the whole functions.php code. But I will post it anyway if you insist.

Comment: @Death.System sure, but do you ever actually then include `functions.php` in your bg_image.php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file doesn't know about used function. You need to add `include` statement.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_STRICT); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include('path-to/functions.php');
header("Content-type: text/css"); 
?>

#logo_main{
    background:url('<?php echo get_settings('ld_header_img'); ?>') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Nothing. I've tried including and requiring, but nothing shows the input from the wordpress settings... I've tried

    content:"<?php echo get_settings('ld_header_img'); ?>";

and other once, but still no outcome. I guess css hates functions?

Comment: Add this on top of CSS/PHP file and  display it in browser, maybe its something else.

`error_reporting(E_STRICT);`
`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Nothing at all... Well, maybe it's a bug, or css won't take some functions. Though, it works in <div style="background:<?php echo get_settings('ld_header_img'); ?>"> That's what's confusing me, because they're the same thing!

Comment: And what about `background:url('<?php echo "AAAAAAAAA" ?>') no-repeat;` did you get AAAAAAAAA string in css ?

Comment: AAAAAAAA Will only show if you do a `content:"<?php echo 'AAAAAA'; ?>";`
Not, `background:url...`
Oh, You made me realize something! I've checked the php file through the URL, and whenever I had the 
`background:url('<?php echo get_settings('ld_header_img'); ?>');`
It displayed this error message:
`Call to undefined function  get_settings()`
Even when the functions.php was included...